# Django: How to use get() method in model

Tags: django, django-models

Django: How to use get() method in model

models.py

```
class WorkDailyRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    contents = models.TextField()
    check_user = models.ManyToManyField(
                User,
                related_name='checked_user_record_set',
            )
    target_user = models.ManyToManyField(
                User,
                related_name='target_user_record_set',
            )

    ONGOING_OR_END =(
                ('ing', 'ing'),
                ('end', 'end'),
            )


    ongoing_or_end = models.CharField(
                max_length=3,
                choices=ONGOING_OR_END,
                default='ing',
            )
```

```
>>>WorkDailyRecord.objects.get(ongoing_or_end='ing')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 131, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 368, in get
    % (self.model._meta.object_name, num, kwargs))
MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one WorkDailyRecord -- it returned 12! Lookup parameters were {'ongoing_or_end': 'ing'}
```

I want to get only 'ing' data...

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of objects, use the `filter` method. `get` is supposed to return a single object or raise an exception:

```
WorkDailyRecord.objects.filter(ongoing_or_end='ing')
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving specific objects with filters

The QuerySet returned by all() describes all objects in the database table. Usually, though, you’ll need to select only a subset of the complete set of objects.

To create such a subset, you refine the initial QuerySet, adding filter conditions. The two most common ways to refine a QuerySet are:

filter(**kwargs)
Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match the given lookup parameters.
exclude(**kwargs)
Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that do not match the given lookup parameters.
The lookup parameters (**kwargs in the above function definitions) should be in the format described in Field lookups below.

For example,

```
WorkDailyRecord.objects.filter(ongoing_or_end='ing')
```

With the default manager class, it is the same as:

```
WorkDailyRecord.objects.all().filter(ongoing_or_end='ing')
```

Answer (score 0):

get() method
a query resulting in multiple objects or no result both will cause an exception,

please use filter() instead